# Dired+ doesn’t work on old remote system

Tags: dired, tramp, ssh, remote, emacs27

When connected to an old remote system with Tramp 2.4.3.27.1, the buffer shows no files. With `tramp-verbose` set to 6, I looked at the Tramp debug buffer, then found (anonymized):

```
13:27:21.657267 tramp-send-command (6) # /bin/ls --color=never --dired -algGh /user/user/. 2>/dev/null
```

When I remove `2>/dev/null` and execute the above command, I get:

```
/bin/ls: invalid option -- h
Try `/bin/ls --help' for more information.
```

`ls` on the remote system is part of GNU fileutils 3.16 and does not support the option `-h`. For my regular system I have configured [dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus):

```
(dired-listing-switches "-algGh")
```

*Is there any way to use a different configuration for that remote system?*

What I tried, unsuccessfully:

```
(connection-local-set-profile-variables
  'example.com
  '((dired-listing-switches nil)))
(connection-local-set-profiles
 '(:application 'tramp :machine "example.com")
 'example.com)
```

## How I connect to the old system

The system only supports connection by SSH v1. For that purpose, `plink` and `pscp` do support the option `-1`. So I added to `tramp-connection-properties`:

```
("/plink:user@example\\.com:" "login-args"
 (("-1")
  ("-l" "%u")
  ("%h")))))
```

Now I can connect to `/plink:user@example.com:`.

## My solution

Thanks to Michael Albinus’ [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/64046/5327), I came up with:

```
(defun my-dired-before-readin-hook ()
  (let ((remote-host (file-remote-p default-directory 'host)))
    (when (string= remote-host "example.com")
      (setq dired-actual-switches "-algG"))))
(add-hook 'dired-before-readin-hook 'my-dired-before-readin-hook)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And not to forget the hint in the Tramp manual:

Emacs computes the ‘dired’ options based on the local host but if
the remote host cannot understand the same `ls` command, then set
them with a hook as follows:

```
(add-hook
 'dired-before-readin-hook
 (lambda ()
   (when (file-remote-p default-directory)
     (setq dired-actual-switches "-al"))))
```

Comment: I added detection of the correct host. Find the solution added to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Set `tramp-verbose` to 6, and rerun the test. There will be a Tramp debug buffer. Look for messages tagged with `(6)`, they contain sent commands, and the responses. Perhaps you'll see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question. Have to dig around. Guess this is not a new problem.

Comment: Tramp doesn't send `ls ... -algGh ...`. I guess you have configured `dired` to do so. Check variable `dired-listing-switches` and alike.

Comment: Right. I forgot about my own Emacs configuration tweaks from long ago. Now I wonder wether I should rephrase my question or close it. The new question is how to tell `Dired+` to use a different `ls` command when connected to that machine.

Comment: It's up to you how to continue. Likely, my answer would be "use connection-local variables", but I cannot say yet, because it would require testing for a recipe. And it would require to know which Emacs/Tramp version you use.

Comment: I rephrased the question, and added the Tramp version number. Although using the keyword connection-local variables, I can probably figure it out myself, I think it would be nice if you add an answer here, so that we have a complete Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works for me:

```
(defconst tramp-connection-local-default-dired-switches
  '((dired-listing-switches . "-al")
    (dired-actual-switches . "-al"))
  "Default connection-local dired switches.")

(connection-local-set-profile-variables
 'tramp-connection-local-default-dired-switches
 tramp-connection-local-default-dired-switches)

(defun tramp-dired-connection-local-variables-apply ()
  "Set `dired-listing-switches' in dired buffers."
  (when (file-remote-p default-directory)
    (let ((enable-connection-local-variables t))
      (hack-connection-local-variables-apply
       `(:application dired
         :protocol ,(file-remote-p default-directory 'method)
         :user     ,(file-remote-p default-directory 'user)
         :machine  ,(file-remote-p default-directory 'host))))))

(with-eval-after-load 'dired
  (tramp-compat-funcall
   'connection-local-set-profiles
   '(:application dired)
   'tramp-connection-local-default-dired-switches)

  (add-hook
    'dired-mode-hook
    #'tramp-dired-connection-local-variables-apply))
```