# Tramp with Dired produces unwanted //DIRED// line

Tags: dired, tramp, shell, files, remote

Connected via Tramp to an [old remote system](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/63918/dired-doesn-t-work-on-old-remote-system), when I list a
directory using Dired, I get:

```
  /plink:user@example.com:/tmp:
  total used in directory 549 available 114.7 MiB
  drwxrwxrwt   3 root     root         2048 Mar 24 06:59 .
  drwxr-xr-x  19 root     root         1024 Sep 12  2011 ..
  drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root        12288 Oct 30  1998 lost+found
  -rw-------   1 root     root       446528 Mar 24 06:59 quota.user
  -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        46909 Mar 14 01:07 zman06938aaa
  -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        46909 Mar 21 01:07 zman28862aaa
//DIRED// 69 70 128 130 188 198 256 266 324 336 394 406
```

According to Tramp’s debug buffer, the command that is executed by
Dired is:

```
/bin/ls --color=never --dired -al /tmp/ 2>/dev/null
```

It outputs:

```
total 549
  drwxrwxrwt   3 root     root         2048 Mar 24 06:59 .
  drwxr-xr-x  19 root     root         1024 Sep 12  2011 ..
  drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root        12288 Oct 30  1998 lost+found
  -rw-------   1 root     root       446528 Mar 24 06:59 quota.user
  -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        46909 Mar 14 01:07 zman06938aaa
  -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        46909 Mar 21 01:07 zman28862aaa
//DIRED// 69 70 128 130 188 198 256 266 324 336 394 406
```

I assume there is some incompatibility between the output from an old
`ls` and the current Dired.

*Is there any way to get rid of the `//DIRED//` line at the end?*

The problem is that the presence of this line makes navigation in
Dired super slow if there are many files in the directory. Moving from
line to line can then take more than a second.

Comment: Tramp knows how to handle --dired on old systems which do not support it, and it fixes the output. Which Emacs/Tramp version are you using?

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus `2.4.3.27.1`

Comment: This shall work out-of-the-box. Hmm. Pls produce Tramp traces with verbosity 6 (see the Tramp manual about), and contact us via the `tramp-devel@gnu.org` ML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed by Michael Albinus in Tramp 2.5.0.4. Thank you!